# Dual plot not working

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the figure-eight curve.

```
g1 = Plot[y = Sqrt[x^2 - x^4], {x, -1, 1}]        
g2 = Plot[y = -Sqrt[x^2 - x^4], {x, -1, 1}]        
Show[g1, g2 ]
```

Can someone tell me why it is not working please?

Comment: Remove the last piece in `Show[]` and try again.

Comment: How about: `Plot[{Sqrt[x^2 - x^4], -Sqrt[x^2 - x^4]}, {x, -2, 2}]`

Comment: How is it still not working?

Comment: Try `Show[g1, g2, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Show[g1, g2, PlotRange -> All] that Work! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is

```
g1 = Plot[y = Sqrt[x^2 - x^4], {x, -1, 1}];
g2 = Plot[y = -Sqrt[x^2 - x^4], {x, -1, 1}];
Show[g1, g2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

```
g1 = Plot[y = Sqrt[x^2 - x^4], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-.5, .5}}];

g2 = Plot[y = -Sqrt[x^2 - x^4], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-.5, .5}}];

Show[g1, g2]
```

Show only works on frames of the same size and range

Comment: why do I have to use PlotRange to make it work I don't understand.
event with g1=Plot[f1, {x,-1,1},{y,-.5,.5}] and g1=Plot[f2,{x,-1,1},{y,-.5,.5}] and Show[g1,g2] it's still not work

Comment: PlotRange controls the frame size regardless of values plotted.Remember Show requires frames to be the same size and range.

Answer (score -2):

Just put semicolons after the first and second lines.

But you seem to be unfamiliar with *Mathematica*'s syntax.  Much better is the approach in the comment from @bill s.